# How do disable SDL for new projects in Visual C++ 2012?

Tags: sdl, default, visual-c++-2012

I’m using Visual C++ for homework projects, where input checking isn’t needed, so I must disable [SDL](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sdl/archive/2011/12/02/security.aspx) every time in project properties to be able to use `scanf`. Is there a way to change this default setting?

Answer (score 0):

There should be several, different ways.

For example, #define `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`. You can do this in code, or in "Preprocessor Definitions" in the MSVS IDE.

Microsoft encourages you to use their "Safe CRT" library instead of the standard C functions, for example "scanf_s()" instead of "scanf()":

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163794.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/ad38eb97-adad-46bd-86ad-ed4983184a0f/